# Doubts about why the "for" doesn´t work (python)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Im learning Python from the start, and im trying to do a calculator just to learn the basic.

```
       print("Entre com os 2 valores: ")
        y = input()
        z = input()
       for a in y:
           if a == '.' or a == ',':
               num1 = float(y)
           else:
               num1 = int(y)

       for a in z:
            if a == '.' or a == ',':
                num2 = float(z)
            else:
                num2 = int(z)

    soma = num1 + num2
     print(soma)
```

What I'm trying to do is, check each character in the string where the values ​​were entered using for, and if there is a dot in the input of one of the values, it should convert to float, if not, to integer

But it seems that the for condition is never satisfied even if I put a float type number, because it appears the error of it being trying to convert to int

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Python is _very_ picky about indentation... If the code in your question doesn't match what you're running, please update it. If the code _does_ match, then step 1 is to review your indentation.

Comment: `if a == '.' or a == ',':
            num2 = float(z)` should be `if "," in a or "." in a` a loop will test digits AND symbols

Comment: Are you trying to trying to convert numbers from a non-english source? or a mix of english and non english sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   for a in y:
       if a == '.' or a == ',':
           num1 = float(y)
       else:
           num1 = int(y)
```

tests *all* characters of the string, and converts to float if it finds a dot or comma, else it converts to integer.

It means it will convert several times (wrongly) to integer or float.

Just don't do this. Use the try and catch method starting by the most constrained type which is `int`, since `float` would accept an integer as well:

```
try:
   num1 = int(y)
except ValueError:
   try:
     num1 = float(y)
   except ValueError:
      print("{} isn't an int or float".format(num1)
      raise
```

Let python perform the parsing for you (which can be complex, specially in the case of floats with exponents, signs...)

(note that `1,45` isn't a valid float unless you perform `num1 = num1.replace(",",".")`)